# Function pointers to templated functions

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Assume we have the following function definitions

```
int function_wrapper_dummy( lua_State* ) { }

template < typename F, F* f > 
int function_wrapper( lua_State* L ) { }
```

And the following function

```
template < typename F >
void register_function( F f )
{
    int (*lf) (lua_State *L) = function_wrapper_dummy;   // line 1
    int (*lf) (lua_State *L) = function_wrapper< F, f >; // line 2
}
```

Compiling the above code works for line 1, but doesn't compile for line 2.

Quite humorously, VS2012 tells us:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int (__cdecl *)(lua_State *)' 
to 'int (__cdecl *)(lua_State *)'
```

While Clang 3.3 emits:

```
error: address of overloaded function
'function_wrapper' does not match required type 'int (lua_State *)'
...int (*lf) (lua_State *) = function_wrapper< F, f >;
```

I use templated function adresses in less complex situations, so I see that it can be done. I checked that lua_State is the same lua_State, I've checked the calling conventions, and I've checked for name shadowing. I've also spent 2 hours trying to google the solution, to no avail (no, this is not a member function problem, only freestanding functions involved).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any template argument must be determined at compile time.  In `register_function`, the value of function pointer `f` is not known until the function is invoked at runtime.

Comment: **headdesk**. Ok, no idea how I could have not noticed that immediately. All that I can say to my defense I can say that the error messages weren't helpfull at all :)

Answer (score 0):

This code compiled fine, hadly i got one error "function_wrapper_dummy" must return a value. I don't think there is an error,with this code.

Comment: Have you actually tried calling `register_function` when compiling? Some template errors are only reported at instantiation time.